# too late for me to get there in time

Tags: infinitives, clauses

a. They told me too late to go there for me to be able to get there in time.

b. They told me too late to go there to be able to get there in time.

Are both sentences grammatically correct and meaningful?

I think (a) is fine but I think (b) is incorrect.

Comment: I would say "They told me it's too late to go to get there in time". Much simpler. I am not a native speaker, though.

Answer (score 1):

As an American English speaker, I would say:

> They told me to go there too late for me to get there in time.

I would certainly understand either of your examples to mean the same thing, though (a) would be more natural than (b), the latter being slightly ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I would be able to understand sentences a and b, however they both feel unnatural and make you think about the sentence to understand it.

"They told me to go there too late for me to get there in time" feels a lot more natural and is easier to understand.